# want to extract Last Value from Jmeter RegEx

Tags: regex, jmeter, load-testing

Actual matches are as below:

```
============================================
e.g.

Match count: 3

Match[1][0]=input type='checkbox' name='sheet_id' value="368">
Match[1][1]=368

Match[2][0]=input type='checkbox' name='sheet_id' value="372">
Match[2][1]=372

Match[3][0]=input type='checkbox' name='sheet_id' value="373">
Match[3][1]=373
```

I'm using RegEx as below:

```
====================================
RefName : sheetID

RegEx   : input type='checkbox' name='sheet_id' value="(.+?)">

Template : $1$

Match No : -1

====================================
```

And I'm using `${__V(sheetID_${sheetID_matchNr})}` to get value, but I'm getting `sheetID_0` as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax of  __V function is a little bit incorrect

As per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V):

> - ${A1} - works OK
> - ${A${N}} - does not work (nested variable reference)
> - **${__V(A${N})} - works OK**.A${N} becomes A1, and the __V function returns the value of A1

Given the following:

```
A=sheetID_
N=sheetID_matchNr
```

Your function should look like:

```
${__V(sheetID_${sheetID_matchNr})}
```

For advanced information on different JMeter functions check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series.

Comment: seems like some other problem with
**${__V(sheetID_${sheetID_matchNr})}** getting Same result as above. **sheetID_0**

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some problem Related to Var Name
i just Changed it to **getSheetId** and now 
**${__V(getSheetId_${getSheetId_matchNr})}** works fine for me.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html